# calling nested function php codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, nested-function

i am trying to call a `function` which is `nested` under other `function` consider a example:

```
function _get_stats() {
    function _get_string() {
        $string = 'Nested Function Not Working';
        return $string;
    }
 }

 public function index() {
    $data['title'] = $this->_get_stats() . _get_string();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
 }
```

now when i run the page in web browser `blank` page is displayed.

any suggestion or help would be a great help for me.. thanks in advance

Comment: try this line `$data['title'] = $this->_get_stats() . $this->_get_string();` I have never find any point in using nested functions... (not closures).

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing it this way? I can't see a benefit to this...

Comment: @Kryten i just wanted to know how nested functions works in php.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Now I understand better how they work too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not really nested, but calling `_get_stats()` will cause `_get_string` to be declared. There is no such thing as nested functions or classes in PHP.

Calling `_get_stats()` twice or more will cause an error, saying that function `_get_string()` already exists and cannot be redeclared.

Calling `_get_string()` before `_get_stats()` will raise an error saying that function `_get_string()` does not exist`.

In your case, if you really want to do this (and it is a bad practice), do the following:

```
protected function _get_stats() {
    if (!function_exists("_get_string")){
        function _get_string() {
            $string = 'Nested Function Not Working';
            return $string;
        }
    }
}

public function index() {
    $this->_get_stats(); //This function just declares another global function.
    $data['title'] = _get_string(); //Call the previously declared global function.
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

**BUT**
What you are looking for is probably `method chaining`. In this case you method must return a valid object which contains the needed functions.

Example:

```
protected function getOne(){
  //Do stuff
  return $this ;
}

protected function getTwo(){
  //Do stuff ;
  return $this ;
}

public function index(){
  $this
    ->getOne()
    ->getTwo()
  ;
}
```

Comment: please could you explain me why it is a bad practice?

Comment: Because messing with function declarations is just bad, code will be unmaintanable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank page, it may be a 500 "server error" response, i.e. fatal error in the PHP code.

`_get_string` will be defined when PHP execution reaches its declaration, i.e. in `_get_stats` when this one is executed.

In `index()` , `_get_string` probably is not declared yet at the moment you're invoking it.

As nested functions are nevertheless defined in the global namespace (contrary to JS for example), you may want to move the `_get_string` declaration.