# how to call function inside function in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to call the function inside function through the url but i am getting the blank page using this code.

**Here is my php code**

```
public function womens()
{
    function undergarments()
    {
        $this->headerplace();
        $this->menuplace();
        $id = '1';
        $query['result'] = $this->Products_model->showwomensubcat($id);
        $this->load->view('womens', $query);
        $this->footerplace();
    }
}
```

Here is Html:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'products/womens/undergarments';?>">Garments</a>
```

Comment: you have a syntax error

Comment: please share the code of view

Comment: There's no syntax error here, but codeigniter does not work like this.

Comment: i don't have any syntax error i just want to call the function inside the function in the url but i am getting blank page using above code

Comment: you are not calling it, you are defining a function inside a function. I don't see a point of doing so. If you want to render a view or combine partials to create a view you can easily do so by loading all views in one function

Comment: in the url you have given above, products is controller, women is function and undergarments is parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public function women()
{
  $cat=$this->uri->segment(3);         // now send undergarments here
  $data['items']=$this->Products_model->getItemsByCat($cat);

  $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('menu');
  $this->load->view('women',$data);
  $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

The way you were doing above in your post, how many function will you create in case you have hundreds of sub-categories. Make things dynamic. With the code above you can send any category. You can even enhance it by using routes or create fancy URLs by using routes but so far what you have asked. the above code is your solution. Just define the function in your model to get your data like

```
public function getItemsByCat($cat)
{
   return $this->db->select('*')->from('items')->WHERE('cat',$cat)->get()->result_array();
}
```

and then render your view

**Edit**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'products/womens/undergarments';?>">Garments</a>
```

Above URL means, your controller name is products, your function name is womens and you are sending the parameter undergarments in url so when you click the link Garments you will be taken to women function of products controller which will fetch all records of undergarments category

Comment: how to call a function inside a function in ci through the href?

Comment: Butt sb, read this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url().'products/womens/undergarments';?>">Under Garments</a>                                                                                      Like if i have antoher method inside womens so i will use "women/kurtis" but it's not working!!

Comment: it doesn't matter what caption you are giving to the link, its the parameter which you are sending, in this case you are sending undergarments, if there are items of this category in your products table and your query is correct then you will get the result

Comment: yes i am getting the result but how can i use the nested methods in ci method and how to call it with link?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017124/calling-nested-function-php-codeigniter

Comment: so i got the solution now i am making different methods for this purpose and using the same view.